# Why does eye see moon glare?

Tags: eye

I started notice moon glare appear larger in darker night.

Does eye see moon glare because of its refraction error?

How much does atmosphere contribute to create moon glare?

Comment: This isn't a health question, and it's not clearly a biology or physics question either, so I'm voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Actually, this is *both* a physics question *and* a biology question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might be better suited for physics SE or biology SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a health question.